# Method openMask not found P4A

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

i'm trying to redirect the user of my p4a application to a dashboard view of my application but after successful login, the redirection to "main_dashboard_mask" comes up with the error "Method openmask not found
login_mask.php line 35"

```
class login_mask extends P4A_Base_Mask
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->setTitle("Login to Dashboard");

    $this->build("p4a_field", "username");

    $this->build("p4a_field", "password");
    $this->build("p4a_button", "login")
    ->implement("onclick", $this, "login");

    $this->frame
    ->anchor($this->username)
    ->anchor($this->password)
    ->anchor($this->login);
}

public function login()
{
    $username = $this->username->getNewValue();
    $password = $this->password->getNewValue();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE
            username = ?";      

    $row = p4a_db::singleton()->fetchRow($sql, array($username));

    if (($row['username'] == $username) && ($row['password'] == $password )){
        $this->openMask("main_dashboard_mask");}
    else {
          $this->setTitle("Login Failed");}
    }
}
```

I'm not sure whether its the index file or something I've missed here, ok now ive gone through again and no matter where i place the function on the page i cannot seem to find the problem, no matter where it is the error continues to occur, it makes me think that the problem is from one of the earlier pages, here they are:

```
<?php

define ("P4A_DSN", "mysql://root:@localhost/login" );

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../p4a.php';

$login = p4a::singleton('login_begin');

$login->main();
```

...

```
<?php 
class login_begin extends P4A
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->openMask("login_mask");
}
}
```

Any help would be very apprieciated.

Comment: Right after looking over the code I've already done, I'm thinking its to do with the function declaration, although within the example file, the coding is very similar for the log in, however the application works fine, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right I worked out What the problem was, when extending the P4A_Base_Mask with the class login_mask i excluded functions that were required (mainly the openmask function) to sort this i simply used the pre-curser for extending P4A (allowing for the use of openMask) this line of code is

```
p4a::singleton()->openmask()
```

so the change in the public function login() was

```
public function login()
{

    $username = $this->username->getNewValue();
    $password = $this->password->getNewValue();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE
            username = ?
            ";      

    $row = p4a_db::singleton()->fetchRow($sql, array($username));

    if (($row['username'] == $username) && ($row['password'] == $password ))
    {   
        p4a::singleton()->openmask("main_dashboard_mask");
    }

    else {
    $this->setTitle("Login Failed");}
}
```

If this is unclear and someone would like to explain it more clearly it would be most welcome, im not entirely sure on what technical terms i should use :)

Comment: Plus for those who have come here because of a similar problem, get P4A known on StackOverflow, ask your questions here, im new to it, but im sure i'll have the same problems to figure out, i will greatly apprieciate the help :)